# How to prevent Razor to modify Html strings

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a message which I want show it's body (which is a piece of html) using razor.

Somewhere in my `cshtml` file I have this:

```
<div>
    @message.Body
</div>
```

While the content of `message.Body` is: `<p>Hello</p>` the created html is:

```
<div>
    &lt;p&gt;Hello&lt;/p&gt;
</div>
```

But I want the result to be:

```
<div>
    <p>Hello</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Html.Raw(message.Body)

more info here: http://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/06/razor-syntax-quick-reference.aspx/

Answer (score 1):

`@html.raw(string)` should do it

Answer (score 1):

What you need is to use `@Html.Raw(HTML_String)`.

Kindly check [Using Html.Raw in ASP.NET MVC Razor Views](http://www.arrangeactassert.com/using-html-raw-in-asp-net-mvc-razor-views/)